# Safari option value is blank but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, safari

I keep running into these super strange bugs on safari. In this one, the option value is blank on **MacOS Safari** or **iOS Safari**. I've tried all sorts of css styling to bring it back into the light, but nothing seems to do the trick.

My google searches have also proven to be dead ends.

```css
option {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</span>
```

Comment: It needs to be in a select element not a span

Comment: I assume this is specific to safari then?

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s related or not. Make it into a select element and test it out on Safari. Hopefully it’s something that simple. But hard to debug if not fixed to check if that’s the issue.